# Django working with Angular.js static file

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I am using Angular as my front end and Django as back end.

What I am facing is my server load the static file really slowly.Although,when I ran the server,the html shows the static file exist, but when I click on the url, it just keep load the file and eventually crashed.This is the 
GitHub link:https://github.com/Honesty1997/my-lotto-game.git

Hope you can help me find the problem!I am sure the django static file settings are all right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some issues with your app

#### 1. miss using double quote in script tag inside `index_production.html`. You need to use single quote between two double quote.

There is many places in your code miss using the double quote, please double check that. You can change your code this:

```
//             +--------------------------------+---- use single quote instead
//             v                                v
src="{% static '/node_modules/angular/angular.js' %}"
```

#### 2. Use absolute path instead of relpath

```
angular.module('app').component('myComponent', {
    templateUrl: "/static/js/app.template.html", // <---- add '/' before static
    controller: ['$http', appController],
});
```

#### 3. Move all your static files under 'src'

```
src
|---facebooklotto
|---lotto
|---static
|---db.sqlite3
|---manage.py
```

And change your static file setting like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

After making the changes above, I can run your webapp. Hope it would help...

Comment: I'll try this!Thanks for help!

Comment: It can run correctly!I will check the Django static file doc again......I think I misuse the static setting.....